# Windows 10 Kali Linux Bluetooth device not showing in search

Tags: bluetooth, kali-linux

I have downloaded my Kali Linux in virtual machine . My Bluetooth is working and it's on but for some reason it not showing any device in search . It just shows searching for devices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect bluetooth devices in windows 10 or in Kali Linux inside your virtual machine?

Which VM program are you using (check if there are any bluetooth settings)

Also make sure windows defender isnt blocking anything from your kali linux install etc (dont think that is the problem here but always worth a try)

Try this inside kali linux terminal:

```
service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: I  have tried that command but it not working . I am trying connect it with kaliLinux In VMware

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying connect it with kaliLinux In VMware –

I have that running here.

Make sure you have connected Blue Tooth to the Kali Machine.

VMware Menu, VM, Removable Devices, and select Bluetooth. Disconnect from Host and Connect to the Virtual Machine.

Once connected, you should be able to use Kali Settings and Blue Tooth Manager to set it up.

[image: Bluetooth in Kali]

.

If you cannot connect Blue Tooth in Removable Devices, that means your host Blue Tooth cannot be connected inside the Kali Virtual Machine.

.

Comment: It's is missing in my removable device option

Comment: Then that means your host BlueTooth cannot connect inside VMware.